# How do we distinguish NP-complete problems from other NP problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology, np-complete

I just learned that when we have a polynomial algorithm for NP-complete problems, it is possible to use that algorithm to solve all NP problems.

So, the question is how we then distinguish non-NP-complete NP problems from NP-complete problems? It seems that all these problems will have a polynomial algorithm to convert into other problems...

Comment: cross-posted to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168664/how-do-we-distinguish-np-complete-problems-from-other-np-problems)

Comment: See also [this question on Mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9221/what-techniques-exist-to-show-that-a-problem-is-not-np-complete).

Comment: A highly related question [Showing that a problem in X is not X-complete.](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/showing-that-a-problem-in-x-is-not-x-complete)

Comment: Any course or book teaching what you have learned should have answered your question immediately after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To provide the flip side of 042's answer: it's important to understand that if $P=NP$ then *every* problem in $NP$ is $NP$-complete (caveat: under the usual poly-time reductions): $NP$-complete simply means 'every problem within $NP$ can be solved in polynomial time with an oracle for this problem'.  But if every problem in $NP$ can be solved in polynomial time—that is, if $P=NP$—then the second part of that statement is vacuous.

On the other hand, if $P\neq NP$ then it's known that the problems that are in $NP$ but not in $P$ have a very rich structure - in particular, there have to be 'intermediate' problems that aren't in $P$ but also aren't $NP$-complete, and in fact an infinite number of distinct ones (that is, such that at least one can't be reduced to the other).  For more details on this result (*Ladner's Theorem*), you might start with Lance Fortnow's [notes on the topic](http://oldblog.computationalcomplexity.org/archive/2003_03_23_archive.html#200039297).

Comment: The empty set and it's complement are not NP-complete (under Turing or mapping reductions).

Comment: @TysonWilliams Not under mapping reductions, which is a good point to make, but certainly under Turing reductions in the sense that a polynomial-time Turing machine with an oracle for the empty set can solve any problem in NP.

Comment: Yes, I only meant (poly time) mapping reductions.  They are NP-complete for (poly time) Turing reductions iff P = NP.

Comment: In short and visually on [this image](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_zUbnTFdqWyg/TGAeo1OxMmI/AAAAAAAAAFA/4MlUdwPvuAw/s1600/800px-P_np_np-complete_np-hard.svg.png) (via [this blog](http://lowlywonk.blogspot.de/2010/08/p-np-biggest-mathematical-problem-in.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Not really. For instance, the [Graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is believed not to be in P, but on the other hand not being NP-complete (and is obviously in NP). Moreover, also all problems in P (that are also in NP) are not NP-complete, if $P \neq NP$. However, to my knowledge, all of these are mere conjectures, since the answer would solve P vs. NP.