# How to prove that problem is not in P

Tags: complexity-theory, proof-techniques, polynomial-time

Given some abstract problem how can I prove that this problem is not in `P`. I mean, what is the method for proving such thesis?

Comment: A [related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/1002/472).

Comment: Let me put it this way: if there was a technique to prove that a problem was not in P, applicable to reasonable problems (such as any of the numerous known NP problems), then the P v. NP question would have been solved.

Comment: @Michael It could be `EXPTIME` problem.

Comment: @Michael All you're saying is that we don't know how to prove that problems in **NP** (or, more generally, **PSPACE**) aren't in **P**. For any complexity class **X** that includes **EXPTIME**, we know that any **X**-complete problem isn't in **P** by the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: well, virtually all problems one encounters in practice are in NP. IMHO a technique that is not applicable to any problem in NP is not general enough to qualify for a "method for proving such thesis". :) That said, you are right of course: occasionally one can prove that an EXPTIME problem is not in P.

Comment: there are many problems studied in theory that are not in NP. although that might make another good question whether any are "encountered in practice".

Comment: @Michael I recommend you read some material about verification. They are very happy about double-exponential algorithms. In fact, often about deciders at all!

Comment: see also [problems that are decidable but not P-time verifiable](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3389/problems-that-are-decidable-but-cannot-be-verified-in-polynomial-time), tcs.se

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most common technique is to prove that the problem is hard for some class. For example, consider the problem HALT in which we are given a Turing machine $T$ and a number $n$ (encoded in binary, i.e., in the usual way), and the task is to decide whether $T$ halts within $n$ steps. HALT is EXPTIME-hard. If HALT were in P then P=EXPTIME (using the EXPTIME-hardness of HALT), which contradicts the time hierarchy theorem. We conclude that HALT is not in P.

Consider now a different problem, REGEXP-INT, in which given a list of regular expressions, we have to decide whether their intersection is empty. This problem is coPSPACE-hard, and so if it were in P, then P=PSPACE. While we don't know for sure that P is different from PSPACE, this is widely conjectured (and follows from P$\neq$NP), and assuming that, we conclude that REGEXP-INT is not in P. We call this a *conditional result*. Similarly, SAT is NP-hard, and so unless P=NP, SAT is not in P.

The unconditional results invariably use one of the hierarchy theorems, and so eventually, diagonalization. This technique itself cannot separate P from NP, due to the so-called "relativization" barrier (though non-black-box diagonalization still stands a chance).

Answer (score 5):

Showing a lower bound on a problem is much harder than showing an upper bound.  For an *upper bound* you simply must show an example algorithm of that complexity (a *witness*).  Conversely, for the lower bound you have show that *for all* solutions each takes at least $\Omega(f(N))$ steps where $f(N)$ is some super-polynomial function.  One simple case is where the output is exponential in the input.

- The [Towers of Hanoi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) is an example problem where one can prove a lower bound (of exponential time) in any solution. The gist of the proof is to show that *any algorithm* must generate each of the $\Omega(2^N)$ positions.

Another example (but one in $P$).

- [Any comparison-based sort is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) $\Omega(N \log N)$.

Comment: You want $\Omega(2^N)$?

Answer (score 5):

The generally easiest solution for this kind of thing is to assume that you can do it, and show that it contradicts a well-established result.

The easiest case will be when you can show that the problem is undecidable -- not in P, not in NP, not guaranteed to halt, ever. Those solutions typically read like:

> "Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an
>   algorithm for the Foo problem. I will show
>   you that if I was able to solve the Foo problem at all, then I would
>   be able to decide if any arbitrary program halted, since I can somehow
>   reduce the question of "Does algorithm Bar halt on input $s$?" to an
>   instance of the Foo problem. The halting problem is undecidable, a
>   contradiction. Hence no such algorithm exists, in particular, no algorithm in P."

Your next best bet would be to show that it would give you a polynomial time solution to something in EXPTIME, and P $\subsetneq$ EXPTIME. That would look like this:

> "Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists an $O(n^c)$-time
>   algorithm for the Foo problem, where $c$ is a constant. I will show
>   you that, in no more than polynomial time, I can reduce some existing
>   problem known to be in EXPTIME but not in P to an instance of the Foo
>   problem, a contradiction. Hence no such algorithm exists."

Anything other than that is hard. We haven't proved very many results about the limits of P.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the question was to prove that something was not in P, specifically, so I think that "Assume this is in P..." would be the most logical place to start. Beginning with that assumption yields you the conclusion "...a contradiction, therefore it is not in P" at the end, rather than "...a contradiction, therefore it is undecidable," which was not what Ari requested.

Comment: You're right, that's better. I edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

of course the big open question is P=?NP as commenters have noticed but you dont specifically mention NP. what neophytes not realize is that there are many problems proven outside of P, its just than none are NP-complete. it is possible to prove a problem takes more than P time ie is "not in P" if it takes eg ExpTime. the simplest way to prove a problem requires ExpTime is to prove it requires [ExpSpace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXPSPACE). this has been done with a sophisticated problem involving regular languages:

- Meyer, A.R. and L. Stockmeyer. [The equivalence problem for regular expressions with squaring requires exponential space.](http://people.csail.mit.edu/meyer/rsq.pdf) 13th IEEE Symposium on Switching and Automata Theory, Oct 1972, pp.125–129.

the proof involves showing that any TM that computes a language using Expspace can be computed by the above problem/formulation. so proving that any problem reduces to this ExpSpace complete problem in the above paper is sufficient.

Comment: Normally, the simplest way to show that a problem requires exponential time is to reduce an **EXPTIME**-complete problem to it. You'd expect proving an exponential space lower bound to be *harder* than proving an exponential time lower bound, since it's a stronger result.

Comment: DR all true yet—all known ExpTime-hard problems are ExpSpace-hard. a problem that is ExpTime-hard but not ExpSpace-hard would be a massive theoretical breakthrough & probably lead to major new class separations. eg P=?L seems to be closely related.

Comment: Quite the opposite! No **EXPTIME**-complete problem is known to be **EXPSPACE**-hard. If any were, this would imply that **EXPTIME=EXPSPACE**, which is expected to be false for the same reasons that **P=PSPACE** is expected to be false.

Comment: To add to this side-discussion, it is worthwhile to note that APSPACE=EXPTIME is known. So an alternating machine that has both non-deterministic and universal branching would actually only need polynomial space for exponential-time problems. Too bad my local computer vendor doesn't have alternating Turing machines in stock....

Comment: @Ruedi Did you look on the internet? Amazon has everything, these days.