# What is an example for a decidable language not in P?

Tags: complexity-theory, polynomial-time

I'm having trouble showing that $P\neq R$. Obviously $P\subseteq R$, but is there  a decidable language which is definitely not (under all answers to open questions s.t. $P=NP$ or $NP=PSPACE$) in $P$ ?

Comment: Please don't ask a question in the title whose answer is the exact opposite of question in the body ("No" and "Yes", respectively).

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/25967/98). [This one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9063/98) has some examples, too.

Comment: In reply to @adrianN, I found both questions by googling "problems not in P" and following some links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are decidable languages that are definitely not in **P**. The [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) says that **P$\,\neq\,$EXP**, so **P$\,\neq\,$R**, independently of the **P** vs **NP** problem. Any **EXP**-complete problem is definitely not in **P**: for example determining whether white has a winning strategy from a position in generalized chess ("generalized" in the sense of allowing a board of any dimensions, with any arrangement of any number of pieces, but otherwise following all the rules of standard chess).